# custom loss in keras (tf backend) requiring tensor manipulation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

My goal is to predict the coordinates of 2 points: [x1, x2]. (The y coordinates of the 2 points are fixed).
In addition of the mean squared error `(xtrue - xpred)**2` , I want to minimize the error from the slope: approximately `(1/(x2true - x1true) - 1/(x2pred - x1pred))**2`.

[image]

Here is my implementation which raised the following error:

```python
Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'concat_1' (op: 'ConcatV2')
with input shapes: [?,?], [?], [].
```

--

## Custom loss

```python
def combo_mse():
    def combo_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        slope_true = 1/( y_true[:, 1] - y_true[:, 0] )
        combo_true = K.concatenate([y_true, slope_true])

    slope_pred = 1/( y_pred[:, 1] - y_pred[:, 0] )
    combo_pred = K.concatenate([y_pred, slope_pred])

    se = K.square( combo_pred - combo_true)
    loss = K.mean(se, axis=-1)
    return loss
return combo_loss
```

How can I slice the output tensors `y_true` and `y_pred`, run some operations and create a new tensor using `K.concatenate()` to generate the new custom loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the shape of slope_true and slope_pred before concatenation. The following code should work. The reason is your `slope tensors` are one dimensions and your `y_true` and `y_pred` tensors are 2-dimensionals. Concatenation operations is allowed between same dimension tensors.

```
def combo_mse():
        def combo_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            slope_true = 1/( y_true[:, 1] - y_true[:, 0] )
            slope_true = tf.reshape(slope_true, (-1, 1))
            combo_true = K.concatenate([y_true, slope_true])

        slope_pred = 1/( y_pred[:, 1] - y_pred[:, 0] )
        slope_pred = tf.reshape(slope_pred, (-1, 1))
        combo_pred = K.concatenate([y_pred, slope_pred])

        mse = K.square( combo_pred - combo_true)
        loss = K.mean(mse, axis=-1)
        return loss
    return combo_loss
```